# Mysql trigger return bad stocks value

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, triggers, stock

I need help with my trigger. I have two tables 'product' and 'storage'. The idea is when I run update on column 'flag' in table 'storage' trigger must calculate stock for right ID, but always return the wrong value for all product, please see attach. Right stock value should be for 'Test' 10 pcs and for 'aaaaaa' 5 pcs. Thanks for help.

[image: result screen]

products table:

```
CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `subcategory_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `product_description` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `product_price` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_type` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `product_quantity` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `products` (`id`, `subcategory_id`, `product_name`, `product_description`, `product_price`, `product_type`, `product_quantity`) VALUES
(45, 11, 'Test', 'test', 1111, 'G', 15),
(46, 11, 'aaaaaa', 'aaaaaa', 12, 'G', 15);
```

storage table:

```
CREATE TABLE `storage` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `flag` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'A'
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT INTO `storage` (`id`, `product_id`, `flag`) VALUES
(46, 45, 'A'),
(47, 45, 'A'),
(48, 45, 'A'),
(49, 45, 'A'),
(50, 45, 'A'),
(51, 45, 'A'),
(52, 45, 'A'),
(53, 45, 'A'),
(54, 45, 'A'),
(55, 45, 'A'),
(56, 46, 'A'),
(57, 46, 'A'),
(58, 46, 'A'),
(59, 46, 'A'),
(60, 46, 'A');
```

mysql trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `tg_ai_table22` AFTER UPDATE ON `storage` FOR EACH ROW UPDATE products
   SET products.product_quantity = (SELECT COUNT(product_quantity)
FROM STORAGE, (SELECT id FROM products) as prod
WHERE prod.id = storage.product_id AND storage.flag = 'A' LIMIT 1)
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

PHP Function:
Cart controller:

```
public function addToCart()
    {
        $id = $this->uri->segment(3);
        $data = $this->ProductModel->selectProductToCart($id);
        $cartData = array();
        foreach ($data as $datas) {
            $cartData = array(
                'id' => $datas->id,
                'qty' => 1,
                'price' => $datas->product_price,
                'name' => $datas->product_name
            );
        }
        $this->cart->insert($cartData) ? $this->db->limit(1)->set('flag', 'C')->where('product_id', $cartData['id'])->where('flag', 'A')->update('storage') : '';
    }

public function updateCart()
    {
        $updatedCartData = $this->input->post();

        for ($i = 1; $i <= sizeof($this->cart->contents()); $i++)
        {
            if ($this->cart->contents()[$updatedCartData[$i]['rowid']]['rowid'] == $updatedCartData[$i]['rowid'])
            {
                if ($this->cart->contents()[$updatedCartData[$i]['rowid']]['qty'] > $updatedCartData[$i]['qty'])
                {
                    $result = $this->cart->contents()[$updatedCartData[$i]['rowid']]['qty'] - $updatedCartData[$i]['qty'];
                    for ($j = 1; $j <= $result; $j++)
                    {
                        $this->db->limit(1)->set('flag', 'A')->where('product_id',
                            $this->cart->contents()[$updatedCartData[$i]['rowid']]['id'])->where('flag',
                            'C')->update('storage');
                    }
                } else
                {
                    $result = $updatedCartData[$i]['qty'] - $this->cart->contents()[$updatedCartData[$i]['rowid']]['qty'];
                    for ($j = 1; $j <= $result; $j++)
                    {
                        $this->db->limit(1)->set('flag', 'C')->where('product_id',
                            $this->cart->contents()[$updatedCartData[$i]['rowid']]['id'])->where('flag',
                            'A')->update('storage');
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        $this->cart->update($updatedCartData);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('category_success', 'Kosik bol aktualizovany.');
        redirect('Cart');
    }
```

ProductController:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Product extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('ProductModel');
    }

    public function index($id)
    {
        $data['product'] = $this->ProductModel->selectProduct($id);
        $this->load->view('HeaderView');
        $this->load->view('UpperMenuView');
        $this->load->view('LeftMenuView');
        $this->load->view('ProductView', $data);
        $this->load->view('FooterView');
    }
}
```

ProductModel:

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ProductModel extends CI_Model
{
    private $table = 'products';

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function selectProduct($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($this->table, array('subcategory_id' => $id))->result();
    }

    function selectProductToCart($id)
    {
        return $this->db->get_where($this->table, array('id' => $id))->result();
    }

    public function insertProduct($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
    }

    public function insertProductToStorage($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('storage', $data);
    }
}
```

ProductView:

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <?php $this->load->view('FlashMessagesView'); ?>
    <ul class="list-unstyled" id="products" data-role="list">
        <?php foreach ($product as $value): ?>
            <li class="span3 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="product_details.html"><img src="<?php echo base_url('assets/img/12.jpg'); ?>"/></a>
                    <div class="caption" style="height: 300px; overflow: hidden">
                        <h5><?php echo $value->product_name; ?></h5>
                        <p><?php echo $value->product_description; ?></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product_footer caption">
                        <?php if ($value->product_quantity == 0) { ?>
                            <p style="text-align: center"><span style="color:orange"><b>Ordered on request.</b></span></p>
                        <?php } else { ?>
                            <p style="text-align: center">
                                <span style="color:green">
                                    <b>In stock <?php echo $value->product_quantity ?> pcs.</b>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <h4>
                            <a type="button" href="<?php echo base_url('Cart') ?>" id="<?php echo $value->id ?>"
                               class="btn btn-success">Buy</a>
                            <span class="pull-right"><?php echo $value->product_price; ?> &euro;</span>
                        </h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: where is your php code?

Comment: Hello, now I edited a post

Comment: Before executing the "insert" query, run antother query that checks for the stock e.g "select count(*) from storage where product='product_id'" after executing the query you can simply run $number_of_stock = $query_res->fetchColumn(); and with this you have the num of the stocks

Comment: So I shouldn't use trigger ?

Comment: @RafaelShkembi Could you specify your hint, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trigger is wrong written, it is make update for all products regardless of id.

To make the changes just for the product with the updated flag change the update statement in the trigger to the following:

```
UPDATE products
SET products.product_quantity = 
    (   
        SELECT COUNT(product_quantity)
        FROM STORAGE, (SELECT id FROM products) as prod
        WHERE prod.id = storage.product_id 
        AND storage.flag = 'A' LIMIT 1
    )
where id = new.product_id
```

What we do is adding `where id = new.product_id` to make update just for updated product flag.

And, i think the way you update the stock is not optimal, why every time you make update, you re calculate the stock?

Comment: Hello, thanks for help. It is because I want to if I have a product in cart then automaticly counted down the number of this product's pieces from product page (as you cas see in first picture). For product 'Test' there is 10 pieces and for product 'aaaaaa' 5 pcs.

Comment: what the values of `flags` could be?

Comment: main idea is: when product is available flag is 'A' and quantity is shown in page, if someone press Buy button and insert product to cart flag is updated to 'C' and quantity of this product is counted down from the whole quantity but when delete these product from cart quantity is counted up back. Finally when the form in cart was submited and product was sold then get flag value 'S' and it is no more available.

Comment: OK, yes but only one part, when I press buy button quantity counted down perfectly for each product but whole quantity for all product was counted bad and issue is in trigger because return all pieces in our example 15 for each product and we want 10 for 'Test' and 5 for 'aaaa'. We must exactly set how much pieces we have for each product. So now I am thinking how to solve that. I am begginer with MySQL so thanks a lot for your help and hints.

Comment: please, can you help me with the trigger for counting whole quantity for each product? thanks a lot.

Comment: how whole quantity for all product was counted bad? the trigger fired when the status changed to `A` and the new quantity only updates for the sold item.

Comment: yes this is working properly, but in the product page there is two product with the same stock value, and as you can see in database model there is for product_id=45  10 rows and for product_id=65  5 rows. It should be 'Test' 10 pcs and 'aaaa' 5 pcs. So I don't know why return all row with flag 'A' for all products, maybe I need another trigger for that?

Comment: Did you mean the number `14` in the picture?

Comment: Is the stock count for each product in the database is correct ? if so, then the problem in the php code which make a select on the database to view the products, could you show the code?

Comment: I don't know.. I added Cart controller code with functions addToCart and updateCart where are all select.