# Subquery returns more than 1 row - even when I use IN clause

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, subquery

I need to create a small MySQL trigger which will calculate price tax. I have looked and searched for answer and tried lot of advices with `IN` or `INNER JOIN` etc.. but I still got this error and I don't know how to solve it. In table `products` there are lot of product's prices and in table `tax` there is only one row with tax value. I need each product price divided with this tax value. Thanks a lot for help.

```
Select  ((Select    product_price_tax
          From      products
          Where     product_price_tax In (Select    product_price_tax
                                          From      products)
         ) / (Select    tax_value
              From      tax
             ))
```

Comment: what if there are multiple product_price_tax and/or tax_value?

Comment: The sub-query that's returning more than one result is more than likely the `Select tax_value From tax` query.

Comment: How is `products` and `tax` related ?

Comment: However this part `Where     product_price_tax In (Select    product_price_tax
                                          From      products)` makes no sense

Comment: Yes the are more product_price_tax -> it is price for each product and only one tax_value -> it is identical tax value for all products

Comment: there is no relation

Comment: @Prdp I would like to ask you if you could look at another MySQL trigger problem. If yes please click [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762200/mysql-trigger-return-bad-stocks-value/40769564#40769564)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If am not wrong you are looking for this

```
SELECT product_price_tax / IFNULL((SELECT tax_value
                                    FROM   tax), 0)
FROM   products
```

`IFNULL` is used to handle *divided by zero* error in case the `tax` value is `0`

Comment: Yes, exactly thanks a lot for help... I spent with this all day